# Homeomorphism definition: why $f^{-1}$ and not another function?

Tags: general-topology

If you have two topological spaces $X$, $Y$ and two continuous bijections
$$g: X \to Y $$
$$f : Y \to X $$
then are $X$ and $Y$ homeomorphic? If not, is there a reason why the above does not serve as a good definition of homeomorphic? To me it seems as though being able to continuously deform $X$ into $Y$ and back again is what characterises two topological spaces as equivalent, and we shouldn't necessarily have to take same route back, so to speak (i.e. we shouldn't need to take $g = f^{-1}$).

This seems like a fairly elementary question, and I suspect it may be a duplicate, but alas I couldn't find it elsewhere on this site.

Comment: I don't know whether the existence of these functions implies $X$ and $Y$ are homeomorphic, but at first glance these seems more complicated than the conventional definition of homeomorphism. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: It is not enough. Have a look [here](http://mathoverflow.net/q/30661/40263)